# numpy multivarient regression with linalg.lstsq

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression

I am trying to solve for m1,m2,m3,m4 in the set of equations such that:

```
y=(m1*x1)+(m2*x2)+(m3*x3)+(m4*x4)
```

Where:

```
x1=[x11,x12,x13...]
x2=[x21,x22,x23...]
x3=[x31,x32,x33...]
x4=[x41,x42,x43...]

y=[y1,y2,y3,y4,...]
```

I have been trying to do:

```
m=numpy.linalg.lstsq(A,y)[0]
```

Where:

```
A = [[x11,x21,x31,x41],[x12,x22,x32,x42],.....]
```

But my results are not matching a similar analysis done in Mat-lab.

Any suggestions or issues you might see would be very helpful!

Thanks.

Comment: Your approach seems correct. It would help if you post your actual data, and what you are expecting to get, in figuring out where may the difference be.

Comment: Jaime thanks for taking a look. Unfortunately I am not allowed to post the data...

Comment: So come up with some synthetic data that exhibits the same problem!

Comment: This helped me: http://adventuresinoptimization.blogspot.com/2011/02/data-fitting-part-2-very-very-simple.html

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are building your `A` matrix incorrectly. Moreover, `np.linalg.lstsq` seems to only accept a `2D` array for `A`, which means that you can do the least-square for one variable at once. Try this:

```
nvar = 4
one = np.ones(x1.shape)
A = np.vstack((x1,one,x2,one,x3,one)).T.reshape(nvar,x1.shape[0],2)

for i,Ai in enumerate(A):
    a = np.linalg.lstsq(Ai,y)[0]
    R = np.sqrt( ((y - Ai.dot(a))**2).sum() )
    print R
```

Comment: Once you do this, how do you implement a regression function that maps a new X to a prediction?

Comment: @rjurney for each time it goes in the for loop you will get a different solution of the least-square, stored in `a`. You can use this to calculate the new prediction, using `Ai.dot(a[0])` (not tested)